# Is there a compilation somewhere all kinds of whitespace: ascii and non-ascii whitespaces?

Tags: ascii, whitespace, multilingual, non-ascii-characters

I am working with documents of different sources (and also different languages) and I am having a lot of trouble with different definitions of whitespaces.

For instance '\xa0' does no belong to this list of wilipedia [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

I want to replace all of them by ' '. For instance,

```
text = re.sub(r'\xa0', ' ', text)
```

Comment: If you want to handle different languages, you need a solid unicode library.  Any solid unicode library will have a isWhitespace method.  Also, any decent regex library has a pattern for matching whitespace already, often `\s`

Comment: Notation is an issue here. `'\xa0'` refers to a byte in a byte string, except in JavaScript where it refers to an ISO-8859-1 codepoint that gets transcoded as an element in a UTF-16 code unit string (which is '\u00A0', which is the only UTF-16 code unit for the Unicode codepoint U+00A0). Since your search space is probably equal to or a subset of Unicode, consider that you might need to read and write Unicode codepoint notation, e.g. U+0020. You can then translate Unicode notation to whatever programming language or other notation you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U+00A0 is on that Wikipedia page you linked to, in the Unicode list.

I'd say that Unicode.org has the definitive list: http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bwhitespace%7D

Comment: I am still learning about this. You are saying that U+00A0 = \xA0?